# How to add my custom compiler to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to implement an editor (eclipse base) which can parse my language and highlight my key works of a file! In addition , I have a java project that runs as a compiler of my language.I want a run button that when I click on it , the java project get the file as an input and print the results on console as an output! How Can I implement it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the **editor** part, you may consider:

- Building your own language-specific editor as described in [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_get_started_with_creating_a_custom_text_editor%3F);
- Leveraging Xtext, an Eclipse project which creates a fully-fledged editor for your language from its grammar: [Xtext website](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).

Concerning the **execution** part, you could:

- Create a run configuration using the appropriate variable to obtain the selected file;
- Use the Command Framework to programmatically contribute the run button.